Short Horror Movie (6 mins?) on Youtube
I know this isn't a typical feature movie/TV show so will be harder to identify.
There is an incredible CGI horror short that was on YouTube in 2008 about a guy who is working late, alone in the office or at his apartment (can't remember) crawls into his computer and there are tons of either ravens or crows that swarm him. Very eerie.
I showed it to my college roommate at the time who was in the art school and he was like holy crap, this is incredibly well done. I'd like to try to find it again if possible. I don't think there is any dialogue to look up and I've searched for combinations of ravens crows computer horror short movie, etc. and can't quite find it.
I bet it had over 1 million views though, it was that good.
Would be surprised if anyone gets it but had to at least try.
